# How do I get a timestamp from an NSString date?

Tags: iphone, datetime, nsstring, timestamp

I have an NSString date (`@"Mon, 01 Feb 2010 20:25:37 +0000"`) that I want to change into a timestamp so that I can better calculate how much time has elapsed from the current time. How can I change the NSString date into a timestamp value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't fully tested this out but it should do the trick.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateWithString:@"Mon, 01 Feb 2010 20:25:37 +0000"];
```

Comment: I get this warning with your code:

"no '-initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:' method found"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `+[NSDate dateWithString:]` if the format is "`2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600`".

If not, you need to construct an `NSDateFormatter`, then use `-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]`.